# what is the use of [0] in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to understand use of [0] in js but still i not get any satisfactory answer.

```
$("#test").click(function(){
$(".test2")[0].reset();
})
```

when we remove "[0]" is not working. what is the use of this is js

Comment: *when we remove "[0]" is not working*. Did you think it means nothing?

Comment: You should follow a tutorial explaining the basics of JS

Comment: what is .test2 ? The .test2 refers to a class and not an Id like #test. It might be more than one element in the result, since classes can exist n-times within the DOM. [0] refers to either the first element of a list, or the 0 property of an object.

Comment: …the basics of jQuery in this case.

Comment: @thsorens Which is really the same… ;)

Comment: @deceze: yes, but for someone not that familiar by the crazyness of JS, it might not be that obvious ;)

Comment: @thsorens there also id actually.

Comment: what else if i use class, then no  need of [0]

Comment: Ids should not be used more then once within the dom. @VISHALSINGH

Comment: so you mean when we are using id , so we have to use [0], but in case of class no use of [0]

Answer (score 1):

`[0]` means first element of an array. `$('.test2')` returns an array-like object of all elements of parent node with `id="test"`that have `class="test2"`. So to get the first child node of the list `[0]` is used.

Comment: As a nit-pick, `$('.test2')` returns an object.

Comment: @Teemu as a bigger nit-pick, even an array is an object.

Comment: @Teemu are you sure about returning an object? Just tested out and got an array... if you didn't mean arrays are objects in JS

Comment: @blewherself [Yes, I'm sure](https://jsfiddle.net/7sjvm4n9/). And I didn't mean that arrays are objects (which they basicly are, ofcourse).

Comment: @blewherself it's array like, I believe it only _looks_ like an array because it has the `splice` and `length` method/properties. If you run some code like this `var x = {length:4, '0':'foo', '1':'bar', splice:function(){}}` it'll look like an array in the dev console.

Comment: It is a regular object, nothing fancy. Numbers are just as acceptable key names as letters. Actually you can even use a function reference as a key name, it is just coerced to a string. If you're interested, how jQuery works, just download its [uncompressed version](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, we can use class name multiple times in a same page, so when we use a class name multiple times in a same page we can use [0] to apply the rule to the class name declared first time or [1] to apply the rule to the same class name declared second time.

In jquery when we are not using [0] in class declaration it also works fine.

when we use id means its unique so we can't use [0] or no need for that.

Comment: when we using id that time have to use [0] to indicate its a first index , when we not using [0] that time reset not working.may be in case of class [0] not needed

Comment: but we can use id once in a page because its unique

Comment: yes, id should be unique. so we are using [0] in case of id.